# Rollup loading css via scss() plugin gives path error

Tags: css, reactjs, rollup

I'm trying to pack a react component library using rollup. I downloaded `rollup-plugin-scss` and put it in my *rollup.config*:

```
export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      json(),
      scss(),
    ],
    external: ['react-dom', 'axios', 'react-redux', 'react', '@reduxjs/toolkit', 'react-audio-player']
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts(), livereload()]
  },
];
```

taken from here [dev.to](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe)

When I launch my build, I get this error:

> [!] Error: Could not resolve './PlayerEmbed.style.css' from
> dist/esm/components/player-ui/PlayerUI.d.ts Error: Could not resolve
> './PlayerEmbed.style.css' from
> dist/esm/components/player-ui/PlayerUI.d.ts

Which is caused by the second option block, and is pretty obvious as in my dist/esm/components/player-ui/PlayerUI.d.ts I got this:

```
import './PlayerEmbed.style.css';
export default function PlayerUI(p: {
    actions: any;
    endpoint: string;
}): JSX.Element;
```

But all the css has been moved by rollup to dist/index.css. Basically, the problem is that rollup didn't update the css path. How can I solve this?

Hint: I got this very same error with postcss plugin too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try add **external** in your options. It helped me in the same problem.

```js
 {
    input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts(), livereload()],
    external: [/\.css$/],
  },
```

Comment: Sorry for my last post. I had find the solution and edited my answer now.